# Input .Rtex file into Latex (knitr)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tex, sharelatex

I am have problems tyring to input a .Rtex file into my shareLatex project using the /input{file} or include{file} commands.

Is there a way to include this as you can do with other .tex files?

The file looks like this :

```
<<>>=
# Create a sequence of numbers
X = 2:10

# Display basic statistical measures
summary(X)

@
```

The code is compiled if I put it in the main.Rtex file, but not if I try to include it. This questions is similar to the [one on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164768/include-rtex-as-a-chapter-in-latex).

Comment: Can’t you just use `.tex` as file extension for the included files?

Comment: @RalfStubner I could do that, but it would not render good. Files that contain this kind of code ned to be saved as .Rtex files, according to [sharelatex](https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Knitr)

Comment: @MatthiasAdriaans, have you considered or tried using [knitr child documents](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/)?

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Overleaf (main file named *.Rtex).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp999.Rtex}
<<>>=
rnorm(3)
@
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\input{tmp999}
\end{document}
```

[image: Overleaf output]

Comment: Actually, I think Peter's comment suggesting child documents is better than using \input.  Personally, now I have a main .Rtex file with .Rtex for each chapter, which I include with something like
<<ch01, child='ch01.Rtex', eval=TRUE>>=
@

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\input` or `\include`, you have to use [knitr's knit_child function](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/child/). For this to work, both, the main file and the file containing the R code must have the `.Rtex` file extension. Other files can keep .tex. For your example, this would look like:

**main.Rtex**

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\Sexpr{knit_child('content/knitr-child.Rtex')}

\end{document}
```

**content/knitr-child.Rtex**

```
<<>>=
# Create a sequence of numbers
X = 2:10

# Display basic statistical measures
summary(X)

@
```

I posted a similar answer to your [linked question on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638265/267056).